# How to fix React build files result in 404 when Chrome memory saver is turned on?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, google-chrome, webpack

I have a PHP Codeigniter Backend with view templates for pages. However, some code is written in React for which the build files are stored in `htdocs/js/reactBuilds`. The menu is written in React and is used across all the pages. To use it on pages that are server side rendered with PHP, there is an empty div (with id=`"forMenu"`) rendered from PHP on all the pages and the react entry js file is written like

```
ReactDOM.render(<MenuComponent/>, document.getElementById("forMenu"));
```

The template file for wepack is empty so webpack just populates all the script tags for the build files of the menu into that HTML template and we load that HTML file in PHP with

```
include(__DIR__."htdocs/js/reactBuilds/menu.html");
```

The issue I am facing now is Chromium recently added a Memory Saver feature, which I am not sure of how it works but I am guessing it discards the assets like *.js, *.css or *.img files from the memory but keeps the HTML file for the pages inactive for long so that it can fetch the assets back when the pages becomes active. However, in some of my cases, when the user is inactive on my site for too long and during that time if there is some changes to the menu code changing the hash in the built js files name on the server, and when the user goes back to the inactive page, it tries to fetch the old js file with the old hash in the name which doesn't exists resulting in 404 from the server (using clean-webpack-plugin in webpack config which removes old build files) which leaves the menu not being fetched and rendered.

One way I have thought we could fix it is modify my webpack config to use **HTMLWebpackPlugin** to add onerror attribute to built script tags to reload the page using javascript on error.

Are there any other better ways we could handle it?